# Am I required to verify if the answer is correct when reviewing late answers and first posts?

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers

I am mainly wondering about late answers queue, but I guess it is also somewhat applicable to first posts.

When reviewing the late answers queue I have the options to press "no action needed", downvote and flag it. Often it is quite easy to determine if it is a real attempt to answer the question instead of something that should be a comment or is downright spam. This does in general not require knowledge about the actual field.

But downvote is something that is often used when the answer is downright wrong, or the solution has major flaws even if the solution "works".

So my question is, assuming I can determine if it is an honest attempt to answer or not and that it is not VLQ or some other flag, should I review this queue if I don't have enough knowledge to determine how good the answer is?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip